# Django's equivalent of PHP CodeIgniter's HMVC

Tags: python, django, hmvc

I'm have developed some web apps using [CodeIgniter](http://www.codeigniter.com/) with [HMVC moduler extension](https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc). And my folder structure of a project will be like

```
Project
| config(common for module1 & module2)
| | database.php
| | config.php
| modules
| | module1
| | | config(module1 specific)
| | | | database.php
| | | | config.php
| | | model
| | | | ...
| | | view
| | | | ...
| | | controllers
| | | | ...
| | module2
| | | config(module2 specific)
| | | | database.php
| | | | config.php
| | | model
| | | | ...
| | | view
| | | | ...
| | | controllers
| | | | ...
```

The folder structure shows that I have **common config** for module1 and module2 and also **module specific config**.
Now, I planned to use Python & Django for a bigger project which has more number modules than I developed before. And I believe the best way to manage scalable app is to use HMVC design pattern. So, can anyone tell me is there something equivalent of HMVC(common config and module specific config) in Django.

Answer (score 5):

when in rome...

First of all, regardless of the merits of HMVC theory, If you're starting your first Django project, it would be in your best interest not to deviate much from what is "common practice" in Django.  Later on, when you get comfortable with it, then you can do whatever change you feel would be an improvement.

Conversely, if there's a pattern that you really like and feel it's best to adhere to, then it's best to select the tools that best embody those patterns.  And if Django makes it difficult to do what you think would be best, then it wouldn't be your best choice.

Now on the specifics.  Django doesn't try to present itself as an MVC framework, the FAQ entry about MTV (model template, view) is a little outdated in that it tries to present this pattern as a "reinterpretation" of MVC; but nowadays it's more like "just not MVC".  Mainly because there's no "controller" in Django.

On first and quick read of the Wikipedia page on HMVC, it seems to be about splitting the controller into more localized code, to avoid a single "god object", and improve modularization.   And since there's no controller in Django, at first sight it would seem that HMVC wouldn't mean anything in Django.

But, it has been said that in Django the URL mappings fill the "controller" concept.  And know what? they're hierarchical and modularized!

So, depending on your definition of HMVC, you might find that Django is already doing it!

But, seriously, when you switch technologies, please leave preconceptions behind.

(disclaimer: I really like Django architecture, as I find it very easy to start and immensely easy to maintain.  At the same time, I don't care a single bit about MVC for web server frameworks, as I feel it's a bad adaptation of the MVC theory as formulated for desktop GUI modular applications.  Ironically, frontend frameworks are deviating away from "web MVC" and rediscovering "GUI MVC")

Comment: `there's no "controller" in Django`

This is not true. [It's simply a matter of naming](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/faq/general/#django-appears-to-be-a-mvc-framework-but-you-call-the-controller-the-view-and-the-view-the-template-how-come-you-don-t-use-the-standard-names). Simplifying, Django names controllers as views, and views as templates.

`Where does the “controller” fit in, then? In Django’s case, it’s probably the framework itself: the machinery that sends a request to the appropriate view, according to the Django URL configuration.`

Comment: `On first and quick read of the Wikipedia page on HMVC, it seems to be about splitting the controller into more localized code, to avoid a single "god object", and improve modularization` Not at all. Take a look to [this TechPortal article](https://web.archive.org/web/20160214073806/http://techportal.inviqa.com/2010/02/22/scaling-web-applications-with-hmvc/). I think this phrase is crucial: `The two controllers; Controller_Index and Controller_Messages; were both executed by a single request to the application. However each controller was unaware of the others presence.`